# Where can I host my app?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm creating an web app which is PHP based. Some more info about app:

- Image processing (not heavy processing - GD extension requried / maybe ImageMagick later)
- It'll mainly display images
- MongoDB is required since app is built on top of it
- Expected tons of people after few days after launch - easy scaling
- PHP 5.3+ is required
- European hosting is PLUS

I want high quality service and uptime as high as possible, but since I'm 17 yo, I cannot pay too much. I also don't want shared hosting.

I've checked [phpfog.com](http://phpfog.com) / [appfog.com](http://appfog.com) and It seems good but it's a bit too expensive (~29$/month app fog, later probably 79$/month and then there is mongo hosting which is 15$/month and later probably 49$+).

I've heard for other hosting providers such as Linode, Amazon web services... But I don't really know which one to pick + what I'll have to know to set everything up.

What are my other options? I've never had VPS (I have my own server home and all testing is done at home), and I probably wont know how to set everything up (postfix, failovers...).

What can you suggest?

Comment: I would recommend a VPS or even a dedicated server out of Germany from `http://www.myloc.de/` because they are VERY cheap and scalable. That's what we use for our European servers.

Comment: @ionFish if Amazon offers free micro instances for a year, and $29 a month is too expensive for the OP. Why suggest a VPS when almost all of them are paid?

Comment: @Anagio - I agree that Amazon may be a good choice for now, but they charge for bandwidth and CPU cycles (after a year or over the limit) and that company I suggested offers unlimited, gigabit bandwidth and CPU processing, it's a static monthly bill. Bandwidth by Amazon in Europe: `Up to 10 TB / month  $0.120 per GB` which is insanely expensive. Do the math.

Comment: @Anagio 29$ isn't too much, but 79$ + 49$ is. I'm willing to go up to 50$ for start.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your app chances are you are not going to get flooded with visitors. If you do hopefully you start making money with it.

So why not go with a Free micro instance (server) from Amazon ec2
http://aws.amazon.com/free/

You can install any server software you need and build your own stack.

Comment: I don't care about chances, there will be traffic redirected from another website 200k page views / month at start, then will probably just rise. I'll definitely check out amazon. Thanks

Comment: Well what the other website does in traffic doesn't mean you'll get all of that or even a fraction. What I meant was when the time comes that you are getting a significant amount of traffic that you need a larger server than a micro instance hopefully you're making money from your app to cover those costs.